# How to resize multiple image using img_library in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, codeigniter

I have an image uploaded and I want to re size this to 200x200, 70x70, 40x40 and every time I re size this it will only give me 2 images the original one and 1 thumb image 200x200. how do I do this? Here is my code:

```
public function resize($path, $file)
{
    $data = array(200, 70, 40);
    foreach($data as $d) : 
    $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image']     = $path;
    $config['create_thumb']     = true;
    $config['maintain_ratio']   = true;
    $config['width']            = $d;
    $config['height']           = $d;   
    $config['new_image']        = './uploads/' . $d . $file;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: i know this is not answer of ur question but you can use timbthumb.php class for image resize dynamically. i used this it work great not need to handel at the time of upload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend calling the following inside your loop:

`$this->image_lib->initialize($config);`

I think what might be happening is that you when you load the library, the initializer is only called the one time. You need to clear out the old parameters, and call the initializer each time you want to make a change.

Also, I would only use shortcode in the view files. Stick to the standard braces in your class files.

Ex. Looping code:

```
foreach($data as $d)
{
  // statements to loop through here
}
```

To put it all together...

```
public function resize($path, $file)
{
    $sizes = array(200, 70, 40);

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    foreach($sizes as $size)
    { 
       $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
       $config['source_image']     = $path;
       $config['create_thumb']     = true;
       $config['maintain_ratio']   = true;
       $config['width']            = $size;
       $config['height']           = $size;   
       $config['new_image']        = './uploads/' . $size . $file;

       $this->image_lib->clear();
       $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
       $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I just figured it out earlier. But thanks anyways you replied. Now I know =)

Comment: Glad you got it working.